# Deploying Bagisto app to heroku error - MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, heroku

I deployed a bagisto app to heroku using heroku cli, configured the env vars and ran the below commands to set it up.

```
heroku run php artisan migrate
heroku run php artisan db:seed
heroku run php artisan vendor:publish
heroku run php artisan storage:link
heroku run composer dump-autoload
```

I've also added:

```php
if(env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
   URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

To the `AppServiceProvider.php` file.

The issue is that the styling is not being applied because of this error.

[image: error]

[image: app]

I'm not sure whats causing this. I tried running `composer update`, clearing cache/config, but I still had no luck.

I tried adding:

```php
if(env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

to the `AppServiceProvider.php` file.